# executing external native build for cmake

Tags: android, c++, cmake

cMakeLists.txt content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wno-error=format-security -Wno-error=pointer-sign")


set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI})


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-camera2-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/jni/native-camera2-lib.cpp )
include_directories(src/main/jni/)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-camera2-lib

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

after run app by android studio.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   13:19:19.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>   13:19:19.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   13:19:19.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > executing external native build for cmake D:\AndroidStudioProjects\camerandk\app\src\main\jni\CMakeLists.txt
>   13:19:19.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

Comment: the error message does not seem to match the posted cmakelists.txt file. What are we not seeing?

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:
    src/main/jni/native-camera2-lib.cpp
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: native-camera2-lib

Comment: i dont know my cmakelist.txt lack of what cause this problem.

Comment: What is unclear in error message `Cannot find source file: src/main/jni/native-camera2-lib.cpp`? You specify non-existent file as a source one.

Comment: thanks so much .cmakelist.txt ,native-camera2-lib.cpp in same dir,only native-camera2-lib.cpp  , not   src/main/jni/native-camera2-lib.cpp .